# what do you mean by subjunctive style

Tags: verbs, subjunctives

The mayor ordered that appropriate measures **would** be taken  to combat the problem of swine flu.

In the answer, **would** was removed because sentence was in **subjunctive style.**

Answer (score 1):

"subjunctive" is not a style. subjunctive is usually taken to mean using **were** instead of **was** in certain conditional situations and dropping the s/es in the third present singular simple present tense after certain verbs of desire, recommendation, advice etc.
For example: "He wishes he were rich."

The most common verbs that drop the s/es in the third person singular include: 
the verbs of 'suggestion' (such as advise, ask, demand, insist, prefer, propose, recommend, request, suggest, and urge) and they are followed by a base verb. Another way to look at this, is to say that these verbs are followed by a subject pronoun and base verb. The examples below are all in the third person. "that" can often be left out.

- We recommend [that] **he**|| **leave** now.
- I prefer [that] **she** ||**do** the task now.
- They propose [that] **it** ||**start** before noon.
- We insist [that] **she** ||**do** it later.

[using a base verb after certain main verbs](https://esllibrary.com/blog/recommend)

This sentence: 
The mayor ordered that appropriate measures would be taken to combat the problem of swine flu.

to be grammatical, should read:

> The mayor **ordered** (that) appropriate **measures be taken** to
>   combat the problem of swine flu.

But you could rephrase the first:

> The mayor **declared** that appropriate measures **would be taken** to combat
>   the problem of swine flu.

The verb **order** is used with an indirect object followed by a to-infinitive **to order someone to do something** and is transitive **or**it is used as **to order something be done** (passive):

- They **ordered us** to pick up the garbage on the lawn. [active verb, to-infinitive]
- He ordered measures **be taken** to combat crime. [passive verb]
  BUT:
- He ordered soldiers to the front line yesterday. [active verb]. order=sent. 
  This last meaning is more restricted.

Also, order can be used "subjunctively" as explained above.

"Right now, I **order he do** it!" However, it is more common to hear: "I order him to do right now!"

"He ordered measures would be taken" is not really grammatical.

- He ordered **us** to take measures.
- He ordered measures be taken [passive] by the staff to solve the problem.

  [order as give instructions](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/order_2)

Answer (score 0):

Subjunctive style (or mood) is the use of a bare infinitival verb in a *that*-clause when it's used with a verb or an adjective expressing necessity (e.g. *order*, *demand*, *vital* etc.).

> The mayor *ordered* that appropriate measures **be** taken to combat the problem of swine flu. (The bare infinitival form of *be* is used in the subjunctive.)

The subjunctive is usually considered formal style and is more commonly used in American English.

Answer (score -1):

You drop the "would" there.  "The mayor ordered that appropriate measures *be* taken to combat the problem of swine flu."  You could also say, "The mayor ordered that appropriate measures [should/shall] be taken to combat the problem of swine flu."  You could use "should" or "shall" in the "that-clause" of the verb "order", which replaces the subjunctive therein, but not "would"; "would" is incorrect English in your example.

You could also say "the swine-flu problem" rather than "the problem of swine flu".  That's a matter of style though.  You used the genitive form "of swine flu", which is more formal.